# Exception RingtonePreference not found

Tags: android

I am trying to add ringtonepreference as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <RingtonePreference
            android:key="pref_tone"
            android:title="pref_tone"
            android:summary="pref_tone_summ"
            android:showDefault="true"
            android:showSilent="true"/>



    </PreferenceScreen>
```

however i keep getting the following exception

```
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class (not found)RingtonePreference
```

i am using the androidX library as shown below

```
  implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'
```

Comment: AFAIK, there is no AndroidX edition of `RingtonePreference`. There is only the native `android.preference.RingtonePreference`, which may not work with an AndroidX `PreferenceScreen`.

Comment: I see ,can i use different preference library with androidx.appcompat ?

Comment: I am not aware of any. You can create your own ringtone preference using a `ListPreference`, though.

Comment: ok thank you , anyone looking this is the solution https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37057453#c2